# Vue native "Element type is invalid" error after initialising the project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-native

I just made a vue-native project using `vue-native init henry-pager` and then CDd into the directory and ran `expo start` to start the online builder gui thingy. When I try and run it in the web - it gives this error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `ExpoRootComponent`.
```

Please help, I just made this vue-native project and started it and don't know what to do now!

Comment: Can you please provide the code this error refers to?

Comment: I literally just ran "vue-native init {projectname}" with a no capitals, no space project name called henrypage and it just says that when I try and run it through web

Comment: I havent written any code myself as well, this is just baseline code provided by the init command.

Comment: You wrote "...into the directory and ran expo start", so there are already project files. According to the error there may be a problem with an import.

Comment: Do you know how I can fix this? It happens with every vue-native new project that I make with the init command

Comment: Search the project files for default exports that are imported in other files with curly brackets. Remove than, that maybe helps. I only know this problem from react, there it throws the same error with: `Check the render method of ExpoRootComponent.`

Answer (score 0):

Even if you use Expo, you should start the project by the following command:
`npm start` instead of `expo start`

The steps that works for me.

Step 0: Install vue-native-cli

```
npm install --global vue-native-cli
```

Step 1: Install Expo CLI globally

```
$ npm install --global expo-cli
```

Step 2: Create a new project using the CLI’s init command

```
$ vue-native init <projectName>
```

Now `cd` into the newly created directory and start the development server.

```
$ cd <projectName>
$ npm start
```